# cannot read and write as private IAM user AWS S3 bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip, amazon-iam

I have created a bucket on S3 and I want it to be a private bucket so no one with a direct link of any object can access that object, and all objects of this bucket can only be accessed through my app.

I have developed my app in *Ruby on Rails*, deployed on *Heroku*, and using *PaperClip* for file storage.

As I don't want public access, I have blocked public access, in ***Public Access Settings*** under ***Permissions*** tab of bucket dashboard.

settings screenshot image:
[image]
I have created an IAM user and also created an IAM Policy and assigned to that user. This is my policy. 
However I receive, **Access Denied** error

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In my `production.rb`, I am using S3 credentials for Paperlcip as follows:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: {
      bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
      access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
      s3_region: ENV['AWS_REGION'],
    }
  }
```

And I have defined these environment variables in Heroku. Access Key ID and Secret Access Key are that of my IAM user.

In my `paperclip.rb`, I have:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3.amazonaws.com'
```

**ERROR:**

The error that I receive in my Chrome console is `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)`

Comment: What command are you using to access S3 and what is the exact error message? Which credentials are you using and how have you supplied them to your app? You can test the credentials by using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) (eg `aws s3 ls my-bucket`).

Comment: I have updated my question. I am using credentials of IAM user as environment variables and defined variables in heroku.

Comment: The error that I receive in my Chrome console is "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)"

Comment: What is the actual API request that was denied? What 'resource' was it trying to load? You could connect to the server and try testing your credentials with the AWS CLI. CloudTrail might also be able to offer some hints as to what is happening.